# pig - I get "Error: Java heap space" with hundreds of thousands tuples

Tags: java, apache-pig

I have three sets of data separated by their type, usually there's only few hundred tuples for each uid. But (propably due some bug) there are few uids with up to 200000-300000 rows of data.

StuffProcessor throws heap space error sometimes when there's too many tuples in single databag. How should I fix this? Can I check somehow if there's for example 100000+ tuples for single uid and then split data into smaller batches?

I am completely new with pig and have almost no idea what I am doing.

```
-- Create union of the three stuffs 
stuff = UNION stuff1, stuff2, stuff3;

-- Group data by uid
stuffGrouped = group stuff by (long)$0;

-- Process data
processedStuff = foreach stuffGrouped generate StuffProcessor(stuff);

-- Flatten the UID groups into single table
flatProcessedStuff = foreach processedStuff generate FLATTEN($0);

-- Separate into different datasets by type, these are all schemaless
processedStuff1 = filter flatProcessedStuff by (int)$5 == 9;
processedStuff2 = filter flatProcessedStuff by (int)$5 == 17;
processedStuff3 = filter flatProcessedStuff by (int)$5 == 20;

-- Store everything into separate files into HDFS
store processedStuff1 into '$PROCESSING_DIR/stuff1.txt';
store processedStuff2 into '$PROCESSING_DIR/stuff2.txt';
store processedStuff3 into '$PROCESSING_DIR/stuff3.txt';
```

Cloudera cluster should have 4GB heap space allocated

This might actually have something to do with cloudera users, since I haven't been able to reproduce this problem with certain users (piggy user vs hdfs user).

Comment: How much memory do you allocate to the JVM?

Comment: @SJuan76 Cloudera cluster should have 4GB allocated

Answer (score 1):

If your UDF doesn't really need to see all the tuples belonging to a key at the same time, you may want to implement the [Accumulator](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigAccumulatorSpec) interface in order to process them by smaller batches. You can also consider implementing the [Algebraic](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/Algebraic.html) interface to speed up the process.

The builtin [COUNT](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.10.0/org/apache/pig/builtin/COUNT.java) is the perfect example.

Comment: Normally my UDF would need to see all the tuples belonging to single uid at the same time. But this is not currently possible for some rare uids containing too much data.